# Comunicar dos componentes hermanos en React

Tags: reactjs

pueden ayudarme por favor??

Tengo un componente en react llamado "Header" donde pinto un botón para desplegar un menú de opciones, este menú de opciones es otro componente separado llamado "MenuOptions"

Lo que quisiera hacer es poder dar click al botón que esta en el componente Header y pasarle de alguna forma las props para que le lleguen al componente MenuOptions y pueda desplegarse el menú.

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor has el [tour], consulta [ask] y luego ve a [edit] tu pregunta. Debes mostrar lo que has intentado hasta ahora. De no ser así, no podremos ayudarte.

Answer (score 3):

Dado que en React el flujo de datos es en [un sentido](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-2-build-a-static-version-in-react), lo que deberías hacer es crear un [estado](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) en el componente que agrupe al *Header* y al *Menú*. Luego al Header le pasás una función que llame al `setState` y al Menú el estado propiamente dicho:

```javascript
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// Componente padre
() => {
    const [abierto, setAbierto] = useState(false);
    const manejarBotonMenu = () => useState(abierto => !abierto);

    return (
        <div>
            <Header manejarClick={manejarBotonMenu}/>
            <Menu abierto={abieto}/>
        <div/>
    )
}

// Header
({manejarClick}) => {

    return (
      <button onClick={manejarClick}>
        Desplegar menú
      </button>
    )
}

// Menu
({abierto}) => {

    return (
        abierto && (
            <div>
               // Resto del menú. 
               // No tiene que estar encerrado en un div,
               // esto fue solo a modo de ejemplo.
            </div>
        )
    )
}
```

También podrías usar [Contexts](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/context.html), pero en tu caso me parece que lo anterior es mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Hola totalmente acertada la solución anterior , mi recomendación es ayudate con ese ejemplo pero estudia los fundamentos de React , como funciona ,base fundamental es entender las props y el state , como pasar funciones entre uno y otro , rederizados condicionales , iteraciones , Hooks  si no tienes buenas bases de JS da un paso atras de vez en cuando y estudia JS , este tipo de problemas te sucede porque tus bases estan en proceso todavia te lo digo en base a mi propia experiencia.Porque quizas no entiendas bien el ejemplo anterior.